# Typescript: Extend interface dynamically by adding new fields with certain naming

Tags: reactjs, typescript, interface, react-context, openapi-generator

I have an interface like this:

```
interface ProjectCostData {
  purchasePrice: number;
  propertyValue: number;
  recentlyDamaged: boolean;
}
```

Now I want to create an interface like this dynamically based on the interface above:

```
interface ProjectCostDataWithSetters {
  purchasePrice: number;
  setPurchasePrice: Dispatch<SetStateAction<number>>;
  propertyValue: number;
  setPropertyValue: Dispatch<SetStateAction<number>>;
  recentlyDamaged: boolean;
  setRecentlyDamage: Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>;
}
```

--> Map over the first interface and for each entry A add a new entry B with the key `set${entryKey}` and a type that can be derived from entry A.

Is this possible in TS?

Background: I have a backend based on OpenAPI that provides me the API structure as a `.yaml` file. I pass that file through a generator and receive interfaces and functions to talk to the API. In the frontend I am using react context to build a global state. I would like to build my global react context based on the output of the generator.

Comment: Is this generator not able to make these setting interfaces for you as well?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of :/ It's a generator for typescript in combination with fetch and what I need is very react specific. The generated code is too generic for my usecase.

Comment: I see. If the logic to implement setters is sufficiently generic, you could implement the them in a single function over the `keyof` of your interface, like `function setProp<I, K extends keyof I>(obj: I, prop: K): Dispatch<SetStateAction<I[K]>> { /* use ``obj[prop]: I[K]`` here */ }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In typescript 4.0 or older, this isn't possible. Strings, including property names, are either fully known as constants (i.e. `"foo"`), one of a set of limited possibilities of constants (i.e. `"foo" | "bar"`), or just any string with any content (`string`). So you cannot construct new property names based on other property names.

---

However, Typescript 4.1 (currently beta) has some features that may help here in [template literal types](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-1-beta/#template-literal-types)

```
interface ProjectCostData {
  purchasePrice: number;
  propertyValue: number;
  recentlyDamaged: boolean;
}

// Create a new setter property for each key of an interface
type WithSetters<T extends { [k: string]: any }> = T & {
    [K in keyof T & string as `set_${K}`]: (newValue: T[K]) => void
}

// Testing
declare const obj: WithSetters<ProjectCostData>
obj.purchasePrice // number
obj.set_purchasePrice(123) // (newValue: number) => void
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-dev.20200921#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApQPYCsILAYQwGcwAROMOZAbwFgAoZZABwFcoEALOIidYJAC5kIVgFsARtADcDJs0zNoYAJ4A1OABtWEYaMky5yKLgjhNK8mLgBzCABNhEjBk0Q4IWfQC+DBgHp-ZHwTChQqEAgAd2ReMEgoFkVlFWQYDET3LmQAawhUjBhkD2RQBPgkBlUlZAB1YDBOAGUIeOgiAB4AFWQIAA9IEHsiGmQAbRzhEihQGwBdYQ9U7wA+ZABeZB6AMhojJjGAaVKQXPzCreRd6dnikYADOIB9ABJqQ+97heQACkiojTaXRbI5zACUGzWADcMMB7AxfPQAkEuhASLMGPZcJo4CZkAgMCASMgMBIsMJ6o0Wm0oJ10NhcARiGQKHAVgxSVgAHRsDjcXj8JDIQIicRSKAcslc568rg8PgzJA-ACMACYAMwQkV-aKAnR6MXQCHraGw+xAA)

That:

```
[K in keyof T & string as `set_${K}`]
```

Is a bit funky. [This PR explains that better than I could.](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40336)

---

You could even handle the capitalization change:

```
interface Capitals { a: 'A', b: 'B', c: 'C' /* ... */, p: 'P' }

type Capitalize<T extends string> =
    T extends `${infer First}${infer Rest}`
        ? First extends keyof Capitals
            ? `${Capitals[First]}${Rest}`
            : T
        : T


type SetterName<T extends string> = `set${Capitalize<T>}`

type SetPropName = SetterName<'propName'> // type: "setPropName"
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-dev.20200921&ssl=6&ssc=9&pln=8&pc=12#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMJwA7DHANgZ2QG9k4AuZAcgEFKAaZAIwsoCF7kEXVLkB6AFTIAdKOQC+DDCwAKvAL4BYAFAqwATwwp0WHLmAAvCAB4AKsggAPSCAAmhfGCigA5gD5kAXhXJfyc1Y29sgABgAkRKAw0MgAYsBQjvIRUTEAShBJIT5+uQD8cQmOFtYQdoQA1hDqAPYwaJjYePg5uW3IBeFEOk0EANrxiWAAuslEGVmt7X4UplO5sypLyhpayADKEGCQUABycAC2JgGl5ciOziDuXqH4WxE9eobHbvLZqiuaKJtgMlA1GH2RxuPx2QJMlAw-0BhwglA8fD4yFWEAoACI7r9oeC0UA)

Putting all that together gets a bit tricky, especially on the beta release. But I think, in theory, all the pieces exist to pull off this type transformation.